# ¿Qué es lo que hace Git rebase --skip?

Tags: git

Ejecuté

```
git fetch -p
```

y después

```
git rebase origin master
```

pero me devolvió un error por qué otra persona realizó cambios en un archivo que yo también modifique. ¿con --skip que es lo que pasaría?

Answer (score 1):

Imagina el siguiente escenario, acabas de mandar los cambios a un archivo CSS en un commit que dice:

1. Commit uno: "Mis menus super chidos"

Después tratas de mandar un nuevo commit con algunos otros cambios al CSS de los menus chidos o geniales con:

1. Commit dos: "Mis menus mejorados con efectos"

Pero resulta que este ultimo te da problemas y te aparece un error similar a este:

error: could not apply fa39187... something

Entonces para "saltarte" por usar alguna expresión este error, lo que haces es:

```
git rebase --skip
```

**¿POR QUÉ LO TENGO QUE HACER?**

> Bueno bajo un escenario similar te ayudará a mandar tus commits a la
>   rama remota evitando usar el commit problemático, ignorándolo por
>   decirlo de algún modo

Answer (score 0):

> Respues [¿Qué hace exactamente `git rebase --skip`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9539315/8933039) (Traducida del Inglés)

Hace lo que dice, **omite una confirmación**. Si se ejecuta `rebase --abort` en un conflicto posterior durante el mismo `rebase`, la confirmación omitida se revertirá también.

Si su cambio ya existía en sentido ascendente, `Git` no podrá aplicar su confirmación (pero generalmente debe omitirlo automáticamente, si el parche es exactamente el mismo). Se omitirá su propia confirmación, pero el cambio seguirá existiendo en `HEAD` actual, porque ya se aplicó en sentido ascendente.

Deberías asegurarte de que no eliminaste un cambio importante tuyo;) (usa el reflog para volver al estado anterior a la `rebase`).

> Este ejemplo de esta respuesta [¿Qué es exactamente lo que hace `git rebase --skip` durante una rebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48324452/8933039) por el usuario [Code-Apprentice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1440565/code-apprentice)

Si hay un conflicto, `git rebase --skip` simplemente omite todo el compromiso. Esa confirmación no estará en la historia luego de que la `rebase` finalice exitosamente.

```
A-B-C <- master
 \
  D-E <- foo
```

Ahora decir que `D` causa un conflicto después

```
git checkout foo
git rebase master
```

Entonces los resultados en `git rebase --skip`

```
A-B-C <- master
     \
      E' <- foo
```

Donde `E` contiene los mismos cambios textuales que E.